# Combining two data.frames in R with left-join

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame called "A":

```
structure(list(ID = c(111L, 222L, 333L, 
444L, 555L, 666L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

along with the following data.frame called "B":

```
structure(list(ID = c(111L, 222L, 444L, 
555L, 777L, 888L), Created.At = c("2018-10-31 06:25:20", 
"2019-01-19 15:42:19", "2019-01-19 15:42:50", "2020-06-30 22:04:54", 
"2019-01-19 15:51:48", "2019-01-19 15:51:48")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to have the follwing output while combining data.frame A & B and then sorting by the ID having a left-join on data.frame A:

[image]

Comment: I think I'm missing something, but: (1) _"with left-join"_, `left_join(A, B)` works, though adding `by="ID"` is encouraged; (2) _"sorting by the ID"_, `%>% arrange(ID)` is direct. Creation of `Flg` is simple enough (see @s_baldur's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
C     <- left_join(A, B, by="ID")
C$Flg <- if_else(is.na(C$Created.At), "N", "Y")

#    ID          Created.At Flg
# 1 111 2018-10-31 06:25:20   Y
# 2 222 2019-01-19 15:42:19   Y
# 3 333                <NA>   N
# 4 444 2019-01-19 15:42:50   Y
# 5 555 2020-06-30 22:04:54   Y
# 6 666                <NA>   N
```

Comment: Thanks but I got the following error: function (...)  .Primitive("c")  ; do you run the 2 code lines together ?

Comment: First you run one line then the next.  The `C`  is upper case, maybe use another name.

Comment: thank you again, it works but I got row records bigger from what I have in data.frame "A"; I don't need to match IDs in datframe B that don't match with IDs in data.frame A. Maybe because I got the same column var entitled "ID" in both data.frames ?

Comment: That means your `B` has repeats in its `ID` field. If you do not want repeated IDs in `B` to do this, then `left_join(A, distinct(B), by="ID")` is one way.

Comment: If you have `D` in both _but_ you specify `by="ID"`, the presence of `D` should not be affecting the number of rows in the results. The only time having both `ID` and `D` as column names in common between the two frames will bite you is if you rely on `left_join` to auto-determine the join keys (by not including the `by=` argument), a bad practice that will bite you. Since this answer is using `by="ID"`, then the presence of `D` should be doing nothing. Check (as I mentioned previously) for duplicate `ID`s in `B`.

Comment: It works thanks a lot; I had obviously duplicates in B. One more thing, how can I sort by ID since " %>% arrange(ID) " is not working. I go the follwing error: Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"